# Razor / SQL UPDATE [Error]: CS0103: The name 'bios' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sql, razor, sql-update

I am trying to UPDATE my database with a new user defined input. I have already created a column(bios) in the table I wish to update. Have my Query as a string and when trying to execute it I am getting an error

> CS0103: The name 'bios' does not exist in the current context

The relevant peace of code is posted below:

```
    if(IsPost){
    userbio = @Request["Bio"];
    currentuser = @Request.Form["currentuser"];

    var db = Database.Open("ResearchA");
    var insertbio = "UPDATE usernameb SET bios = userbio WHERE username = currentuser";  //Update the table with 'userbio' when a username is selected.
    db.Execute(insertbio,bios);

    }
```

Any ideas or suggestions guys? Thx a lot :))

Comment: Does the statement execute directly in SQL Server Management Studio? You're also not using your userbio and currentUser variables anywhere.

Comment: Are you saving data to DB in View in ASP.NET MVC????

Comment: @Maris, no, this is not ASP.NET MVC, it's a WebMatrix page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using some `bios` variable which is not defined anywhere.

So fix your code:

```
if(IsPost) {
    var userbio = Request["Bio"];
    var currentuser = Request.Form["currentuser"];
    var db = Database.Open("ResearchA");
    var insertbio = "UPDATE usernameb SET bios = @0 WHERE username = @1";
    db.Execute(insertbio, userbio, currentuser);
}
```

Also passing the current user as part of a form post looks pretty dangerous.

Comment: Thx a lot Darin. Any ideas on why this doesn't update my table ?! Initial column of bios was set to NULL.